# Which is a quicker way to fetch current_user's post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails, I'm doing something like this - which is more efficient?

```
post = current_user.posts.find(29)
```

OR

```
post = Post.where("user_id = ? AND id = ?", user.id, 29).first
```

I'm guessing the first statement would do something like `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = x` (current_user is a preset User instance) then find post #29 amongst the returned array/rows; however, the second one might do something like `SELECT * FROM posts WHERE user_id = x AND id = 29 LIMIT 0,1` .. is it quicker to fetch all, without any criteria, then let ruby search within the returned array/rows; OR, is criteria and a limit a quicker way to do it; OR, does it depend on the length/width of the table and countless other things? Thanks

Comment: Don't you see generated queries in dev server log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL query in both cases will be the same. So there's no difference in time of execution - but the first statement is more idiomatic, hence should be preferred.